# Amchart 4 not showing bar graph when there is very long label

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

I am using Amchart 4 to visualize the bar graph. I am using this official [example](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/NBWNdm) from the amchart.

Now, the problem I am facing is that amchart doesn't render the bar graphs when there is a very long label. It is not handling it properly. It looks like this.

[image]

This is my js code:

```
/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts V4 preview release.
 * 
 * V4 is the latest installement in amCharts data viz
 * library family, to be released in the first half of
 * 2018.
 *
 * For more information and documentation visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * --------------------------------------------------------
 */

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "category": "First very long category label, very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long",
  "value": 450
}, {
  "category": "Another long category label",
  "value": 1200
}];

// Create value axis
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

// Configure axis label
var label = categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template;
label.wrap = true;
label.maxWidth = 120;

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
```

Now, I just don't want to truncate the label, like this official [document](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/wrapping-and-truncating-axis-labels/). But I would like to have some kind of solution such as truncating labels only if it goes out of some `maxHeight` property. So that way, I can still show full labels which doesn't go out of the `maxHeight` property.

For the live example: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r7wpf3kh/)

Comment: This is not an answer, but feedback : on the JS FIDDLE link you shared ------------------------------------------ [![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFuhH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFuhH.png) you can see, the graph this there... if I got your question wrong, please let me know by reply or comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can this code after initiating your array
Im just going through the categories, and checking for the length, i think the length that breaks the Chart is somewhere around 80-85, its based the context but you can have a minimum safe number maybe 80

```
chart.data.map(el => {
  if(el.category.length > 80){
    el.category=`${el.category.substr(0,40)}...`;
  }
})
```

and modify the numbers based on what suits you.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. But may I know where to add this code? Can you edit the jsfiddle link with your solution and share the updated link?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, can you try to add it, before the line
// Create value axis

Comment: Thanks. You solution worked perfectly. But it is actually causing issue on tooltip text. Can you look into this https://jsfiddle.net/8mh2ud31/ and let me know?

Comment: Am Sorry i tried looking into the library itself but i am not quite fond with it, there is something called textFormatter, but i have no idea how to utilize it, tried and failed :)

Comment: Ok, no problem. The main problem has solved anyway. Thanks for your help. I'll reward the bounty soon in three hours, it's when I will be able to.

Comment: Hey, is there a documentation on the solution you mentioned? I'll take a look myself for the tooltip issue I am getting.

Comment: Nah no specific documentation its just that i took all the categories and removed the extra characters if its more than 40, i used, map which goes through the whole array of data, and "substr" and "template literal", you can google those, pretty straight forward

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks for the help.